# SharePoint Online - Selecting most recent date column between two columns in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint list in Office 365 environment that (among other columns) has two DATE columns, how would I create another calculated column that would have the most recent date from those two Date columns.

Example:

```
ID     Date1     Date2

1      1/1/2016   2/1/2016

2      2/1/2016   1/1/2016

3      5/1/2016  5/1/2016
```

I wanted my results to look like

```
ID     MostRecentDate(Calculated Column)

1      2/1/2016

2      2/1/2016

3      5/1/2016
```

My environment is SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the MAX function and output it in Date format.

```
=MAX([date1],[date2])
```

If the two dates are blank, it will output a default date in 1899, so maybe put in a IF condition in there.

Comment: For all functions that do work in SharePoint see: http://viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List